# Silently log onto Microsoft Graph?

Tags: ms-office, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Since I have my users log in and password, can I silently log into their Microsoft Graph?

I want to fetch info from Office 365 API from a server app, so therefor I cannot have a Microsoft Login Window popping up.

Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't be collecting your users' username and password. The answer by @Jon Knight is the correct (and much more secure) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the confidential client flow for authenticating the Graph API.  See the section "Daemon or Server Application to Web API" in [this document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/) for details.  Of course you'll need to be the admin of you Azure AD, or have the admin's trust and blessing, in order to use this flow as the user isn't involved in the process themselves.

I've been trying to use it for calendaring apps.  The flow login works fine but be aware that there are some limitations on using the Graph API with this authentication flow type (specifically interacting with Unified Groups calendars in my case).